# Remoting to PCs already setup with PocketCloud

Tags: remote-desktop

I use PocketCloud to remote desktop into my PCs on my home network.

I would like to use Remote Desktop with Windows on my laptop via Windows 7 from a connection outside my network, but I'm not really sure how to, without breaking PocketCloud's connection.

Does PocketCloud change my router's port forward to each machine as needed?

Is there a way I can piggyback on the PocketCloud app? It appears to use 3389 but nothing is routed on that port in my router.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. I can create a port forwarding rule for 3389 on my router pointing to my laptop, and connect comfortably even with PocketCloud Companion installed.

However, both sessions will not run simultaneously, due to an RDP limitation in Windows. If you connect with one, then the other, the first will be disconnected. This is normal.

---

PocketCloud uses port 3389, just like a normal Remote Desktop Connection.

When you connect to the desktop using PocketCloud, it throws anyone else off the console (assuming it's not a Terminal Services Server) that is logged in with the same credentials.

I was able to log into my laptop running Windows 7 using PocketCloud on my iPhone. It took over the logged-in session on the laptop.

I then used my Mac to connect, using Remote Desktop Connection, and it kicked me out of PocketCloud. So it's all RDP port 3389.

As to what's happening on your router, it looks as though the PocketCloud Companion for Windows client is tunnelling a session through TCP on a different port. This makes sense, seeing that you sign in with a Gmail account.

I did a `netstat -a` while connected using the PocketCloud client, as well as verification through Process Monitor from [SysInternals](http://www.sysinternals.com)), and I found this:

```
192.168.0.195:1171    pb-in-f125:5222
```

This coincided with Process Monitor, which found that the PocketCloudService process was talking on various ports locally to a remote port of 5222. For instance (edited for brevity):

```
PocketCloudService.exe  2056  TCP Receive  MyLaptop:1171->pb-in-f125.1e100.net:5222
```

Comment: Yep, I can remote desktop from my local LAN. I'm interested in over the internet from a remote location, sorry I failed to mention that.

Comment: I answered that. It starts at "As to what's happening on your router".

Comment: So, I cannot add a route on port 3389, pocket cloud stops working, If I change the default port in windows, pocket cloud stops working.

Comment: That is correct, and it is by design. What do you want to do exactly? If you port forward from the router, it will kill any existing PocketCloud connections, but that's an RDP limitation inside Windows and has nothing to do with PocketCloud.

Comment: I want to have the ability to put in my ip address into the windows remote desktop interface from my laptop away from home and connect that way

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're missing. I create a port-forward on my router, to 3389 on my laptop, and connect through RDP quite successfully, even with PocketCloud Companion installed.

Comment: Yeah, I must be missing something. Doesn't work for me. Thanks for your help tho